# How do I get a Simple Product Name of the Configurable into minicart

Tags: magento2, product, mini-cart

Edit DefaultItem.php file doGetItemData() function as below

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

protected function doGetItemData()
    {
    $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $sku = $this->item->getProduct()->getSku();
    $simpleProduct = $productObject->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);      

    return [
        'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
        'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
        'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
        'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
        'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
        'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName(),
        'simple_product_name' => $simpleProduct->getName(),
        'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
        'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
        'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
        'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
        'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
        'product_image' => [
            'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
            'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
            'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
            'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
        ],
        'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
            && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
    ];
}
```

Then you can use it in below file

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

Replace this

```
 <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
```

From

```
 <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: simple_product_name"></a>
```

Comment: it should work . have u done static content deploy

Comment: Its work only simple product....not working configurable product...any idea

Comment: Yes. That method we can use if the site have only configurable products.